# Is there a limit as to how many lolligators you can buy?

Tags: candy-box-2

I have just finished buying my second **lolligator** and a question popped in my head: how many lolligators are you limited to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested this by buying 50 lolligators. I didn't reach any limit and, since 50 lolligators can convert almost 500,000 candies per second, the number may as well be limitless.

If there is a limit, it would be due to the maximum size of the integer used rather than any design choice and would not come up in any real game.

Comment: Have you finished Candy Box 2 yet?

Comment: @JerryRox Everything except the lighthouse puzzle. I know how it works but it's still insanely complicated.

Comment: A conversion rate of 500 000 candies per second is actually not that unreasonable, seeing how many candies you can/will get after a bit of playtime.

Comment: *"If there is a limit, it would be due to the maximum size of the integer.."* - FYI javascript does not have an integer type.  All numbers are represented as [double floating-points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  There do have a *(ridiculously huge)* max value, but you'd run into precision errors *long* before that.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Interesting to know, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

There is **no limit** on the lolligators you own. The code of the game does not employ any kind of limit.

In fact, to test it out, I bought 500 lolligators and my conversion rate jumped to `2.0582883235125174e+57/sec`. This number is high enough that no one would ever want to get a conversion rate that high, and a limit higher than that would just be absurd.